# How can I use a LazyVerticalGrid with items created from an enum inside a Lazy Column

Tags: gridview, android-jetpack-compose, lazy-loading, lazycolumn

I'm using a LazyGridView inside a LazyColumn as I have content that would exceed the screen height and hence would need scrolling through.

However, doing this gives me an error `Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed`

I've looked at these other Stack Overflow answers, but they don't show how to resolve the issue when my LazyGrid is being created based off values in an enum:

1. [Jetpack Compose: How to put a LazyVerticalGrid inside a scrollable Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919707/jetpack-compose-how-to-put-a-lazyverticalgrid-inside-a-scrollable-column)
2. [Fixed Grid inside LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336555/fixed-grid-inside-lazycolumn-in-jetpack-compose)

How can I resolve this for my code below?

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//EthnicityOptions enum
enum class EthnicityOptions(val rawValue: String) {

    whiteEnglish("English"),
    whiteWelsh("Welsh"),
    whiteScottish("Scottish"),
    whiteIrish("Irish"),

    asianIndian("Indian"),
    asianPakistani("Pakistani"),
    asianBangladeshi("Bangladeshi"),
    asianChinese("Chinese"),

    french("French"),
    italian("Italian"),
    german("German"),
    polish("Polish"),
    swedish("Swedish"),
    hispanic("Hispanic"),
    american("American"),
    middleEastern("Middle Eastern"),
    australian("Australian"),

    blackAfrican("African"),
    blackCaribbean("Caribbean"),

    miscMixed("Mixed"),
    miscOther("Other"),
}




//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//AlertMessageViewModel
class AlertMessageViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var showAlert: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//OnboardingProfileEthnicityView
@Composable
fun OnboardingProfileEthnicityView(
    alertViewModel: AlertMessageViewModel,
) {

    var ethnicitySelection by remember { mutableStateOf("") }


    val animatedBlur: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (alertViewModel.showAlert) {
            alertBlurRadius
        } else {
            0.dp
        }
    )


    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .blur(animatedBlur)
        ) {


            LazyColumn {

                item {
                    Column {

                        Column(
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(30.dp),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding((cardPadding), (cardPadding))
                                .padding(30.dp, 25.dp),
                        ) {


                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            ) {

                                Text(
                                    text = "Select your ethnicity:",
                                    style = TextStyle(
                                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                            Color.White
                                        } else {
                                            Color.Black
                                        }
                                    ),
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                                )
                            }


                            LazyVerticalGrid(
                                columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
                            ) {
                                items(EthnicityOptions.values()) { ethnicity ->

                                    Text(
                                        text = ethnicity.rawValue,
                                        style = TextStyle(
                                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                            fontSize = 15.sp,
                                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                            color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                if (ethnicitySelection == ethnicity.rawValue) {
                                                    Color.Black
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.White
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if (ethnicitySelection == ethnicity.rawValue) {
                                                    Color.White
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.Black
                                                }
                                            },
                                        ),
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .clickable(
                                                enabled = !alertViewModel.showAlert,
                                                onClick = {
                                                    if (ethnicitySelection == ethnicity.rawValue) {
                                                        ethnicitySelection = ""
                                                    } else {
                                                        ethnicitySelection =
                                                            ethnicity.rawValue
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                                                indication = null
                                            )
                                            .border(
                                                width = 1.dp,
                                                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                    Color.White
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.Black
                                                },
                                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(cardCornerRadius)
                                            )
                                            .background(
                                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(cardCornerRadius),
                                                color =
                                                if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                    if (ethnicitySelection == ethnicity.rawValue) {
                                                        Color.White
                                                    } else {
                                                        Color.Black
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    if (ethnicitySelection == ethnicity.rawValue) {
                                                        Color.Black
                                                    } else {
                                                        Color.White
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            )
                                            .padding(0.dp, 10.dp)
                                    )

                                }
                            }


                            //Icons
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(30.dp)
                            ) {


                                //Privacy Information
                                Column(
                                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
                                ) {
                                    Row(
                                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
                                    ) {

                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.PrivacyTip,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(15.dp),
                                            tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            } else {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            },
                                        )


                                        Text(
                                            text = "Privacy Information",
                                            style = TextStyle(
                                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                                                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                }
                                            )
                                        )
                                    }


                                    Row(
                                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
                                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .offset(5.dp, 0.dp)
                                    ) {
                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Circle,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(4.dp)
                                                .offset(0.dp, 6.dp),
                                            tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            } else {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            },
                                        )

                                        Text(
                                            text = "Privacy Information 1.",
                                            style = TextStyle(
                                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                }
                                            )
                                        )

                                    }


                                    Row(
                                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
                                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .offset(5.dp, 0.dp)
                                    ) {
                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Circle,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(4.dp)
                                                .offset(0.dp, 6.dp),
                                            tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            } else {
                                                Color.Gray
                                            },
                                        )

                                        Text(
                                            text = "Privacy Information 2.",
                                            style = TextStyle(
                                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                } else {
                                                    Color.Gray
                                                }
                                            )
                                        )

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }


                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))


                        Row(
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(cardPadding),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(cardPadding, 0.dp)
                        ) {

                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    //Move to previous view
                                },
                                enabled = !alertViewModel.showAlert,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .weight(1f),
                                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                                    backgroundColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                        Color.Black
                                    } else {
                                        Color.White
                                    }
                                ),
                                elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(defaultElevation = 0.dp)
                            ) {
                                Row(
                                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                                ) {

                                    Icon(
                                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ChevronLeft,
                                        contentDescription = "null",
                                        tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                            Color.White
                                        } else {
                                            Color.Black
                                        },
                                    )

                                    Text(
                                        text = "Back",
                                        style = TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                        ),
                                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                            Color.White
                                        } else {
                                            Color.Black
                                        }
                                    )

                                }
                            }


                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    //Move to next view
                                },
                                enabled = !alertViewModel.showAlert,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .weight(1f),
                                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                                    backgroundColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                        Color.Black
                                    } else {
                                        Color.White
                                    }
                                ),
                                elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(defaultElevation = 0.dp)
                            ) {
                                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

                                    Text(
                                        text = "Next",
                                        style = TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                        ),
                                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                            Color.White
                                        } else {
                                            Color.Black
                                        }
                                    )

                                    Icon(
                                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ChevronRight,
                                        contentDescription = "null",
                                        tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                            Color.White
                                        } else {
                                            Color.Black
                                        },
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        Spacer(Modifier.height(cardPadding))


                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (alertViewModel.showAlert) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(0.dp, (-25).dp)
            ) {
                //AlertView to be added here
            }
        }

    }


}
```